# Description in the bottom design can't same line, same height element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the problem about css for make a same height. I have a the list designs and every design have description in the bottom, in my case, I already to make design middle of portrait and landscape,
but if the description have the long text can't same line with other. I want to the description 
flat top only using css not javascript, like a image bellow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWb6p.png)

I using the bootstrap flex

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8 p-4 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="my-auto">
      <img/>
    </div>
    <div class="description my-3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8 p-4 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="my-auto">
      <img/>
    </div>
    <div class="description my-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-column {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
}
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

Please help me for fixing my problem, thank you for your help, sorry my english is bad

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Same height</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 p-4 d-flex flex-column border">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 p-4 d-flex flex-column border">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat repellendus, molestias animi deleniti cum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 p-4 d-flex flex-column border">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 p-4 d-flex flex-column border">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 p-4 d-flex flex-column border">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 p-4 d-flex flex-column border">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How about remove `d-flex flex-column` class, set fixed height and  width 100% for `my-auto`?

Comment: the result like this https://jsfiddle.net/harasya/e1p8tk6f/15/ 
the image not a middle

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4z51yja/ .The image is now in the middle

Comment: Thank you so much, is working now

Comment: But we need set the height? the problem if design is dynamic height every loop, have the long space within description and design

Comment: Yeah you need to set a fixed height, so the description text will be displayed in the same line. I've set the img `max-height 100%` so it will not overflow when the img height is too big. Can I post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this working example. You just need to add the fixed height to class 
`my-auto` +  `vertical-align: middle;`, then all product description will stay in the same line. Don't forget to add `max-height: 100%` to image to avoid overflow.

Hope this helps.

```css
.my-auto {
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.my-auto img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Same height</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 p-4 border">
      <div class="my-auto w-100">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-4 border">
      <div class="my-auto w-100">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat repellendus, molestias animi deleniti cum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-4 border">
      <div class="my-auto w-100">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/0000FF/808080" class="w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="my-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```